# No product data specified to create product [woocommerce_api_missing_product_data]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes, woocommerce-rest-api

I have downloaded latest repository of woocommerce php API. I have been following woocommerce REST API Docs to create a test product. I have copied the sample from their documentation but it is not working. Here is my code.

API docs : http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-a-product

```
<?php

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://wocom.dev', 
    'ck_c62182de9983593c9da6ed5c4642ff50e79e1b4f', 
    'cs_8f69a9d588abb9ca1b0309f22ac2cd7841496d56',
    [
        'version' => 'v3',
        'ssl_verify'=> 'false',
        'timeout' => 30000
    ]
);



$data = [
    'name' => 'Ship Your Idea',
    'type' => 'variable',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_4_front.jpg',
            'position' => 0
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_4_back.jpg',
            'position' => 1
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_3_front.jpg',
            'position' => 2
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_3_back.jpg',
            'position' => 3
        ]
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'id' => 6,
            'position' => 0,
            'visible' => false,
            'variation' => true,
            'options' => [
                'Black',
                'Green'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Size',
            'position' => 0,
            'visible' => true,
            'variation' => true,
            'options' => [
                'S',
                'M'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'default_attributes' => [
        [
            'id' => 6,
            'option' => 'Black'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Size',
            'option' => 'S'
        ]
    ],
    'variations' => [
        [
            'regular_price' => '19.99',
            'image' => [
                [
                    'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_4_front.jpg',
                    'position' => 0
                ]
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                [
                    'id' => 6,
                    'option' => 'black'
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Size',
                    'option' => 'S'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            'regular_price' => '19.99',
            'image' => [
                [
                    'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_3_front.jpg',
                    'position' => 0
                ]
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                [
                    'id' => 6,
                    'option' => 'green'
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Size',
                    'option' => 'M'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];




try
{
    print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Error :

```
Error: No product data specified to create product [woocommerce_api_missing_product_data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$data = []` use `$data['product'] = []`

The woocommerce API is checking to see if `$data['product']` is set, and returns [woocommerce_api_missing_product_data] if its empty.

See [woocommerce/includes/api/legacy/v2/class-wc-api-products.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4dc579ff57c70577ea2e07376eb163db4c37dde3/includes/api/legacy/v2/class-wc-api-products.php#L205-L211)

```
public function create_product( $data ) {
$id = 0;
    try {
        if ( ! isset( $data['product'] ) ) {
            throw new WC_API_Exception( 'woocommerce_api_missing_product_data', sprintf( __( 'No %1$s data specified to create %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), 'product' ), 400 );
        }
```

Comment: I linked to v2 of the API but v3 includes the same statement here [woocommerce/includes/api/legacy/v3/class-wc-api-products.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4dc579ff57c70577ea2e07376eb163db4c37dde3/includes/api/legacy/v3/class-wc-api-products.php#L254-L260)