# wc-api-node woocommerce api missing data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have been working and testing the woocommerce/wc-api-node with my local website for days now, still unable to figure out what is wrong with it?

```
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080',
  consumerKey: 'ck_2617',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_7f51'
   })

export class CreateCoupon{
static createCoupon( ){

const data = {
 code: '10off',
 discount_type: 'percent',
 amount: '10',
 individual_use: true,
 exclude_sale_items: true,
 minimum_amount: '100.00'
}
 //i did try to add this as well coupons?_method=post
 WooCommerce.post('coupons', data, function(err, data, res) {
 console.log(res);
 console.log(err);
   });
  }
 }
 //error {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_missing_coupon_data","message":"No coupon data specified to create coupon"}]}
```

Another setting with latest WordPress, admin login, all set looks good, i am able to get products, but not post :( .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[No product data specified to create product [woocommerce_api_missing_product_data]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316720/no-product-data-specified-to-create-product-woocommerce-api-missing-product-dat)

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4dc579ff57c70577ea2e07376eb163db4c37dde3/includes/api/legacy/v2/class-wc-api-coupons.php

https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-node/blob/master/index.js

I found error using

```
error_log( var_dump($data));
```

solution:

```
var data = {
 coupon:{code: '13off'}
};
```